# Limit hostnames for user

Tags: mysql, mysqltuner

I am running MySQL optimisation wizard, mysqltuner, which gives the suggestion:

> User 'root@%' does not specify hostname restrictions.

How is this achieved? I can't readily find an answer.

Answer (score 2):

`root`, assuming it is the `SUPER` user, should be very restricted.

```
'root'@'my.domain.com'

'root'@'11.22.33.44'
```

In other situations, you might want

```
'joe'@'192.168.%'

'sal'@'%.our-domain.com'
```

Comment: How do you limit to just 127.0.0.1?

Comment: `'joe'@'127.0.0.1'` or (perhaps) `'joe'@'localhost'` -- Note that "localhost" is not included in "%".